# Random Test Generator with Classes

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm relatively new to java and I'm trying to develop a test generator program that in a class called TestGenerator, randomly selects 2 questions from a pool of 5 multiple choice questions in a string array. I've been given hints to create a one dimensional array of 2 rows, within the TestGenerator class, which will be randomly populated with numbers from 0 to 4 which will correspond to the questions from array TestBank. Call that array SelectedNumbers. Whatever numbers are selected, those questions will be asked to the user. I want the questions asked separately through different windows and at the end tells me the score.  As of now I have a 5 by 5 string array, TestBank, in which the first column is the question, the next three are the answer choices, and the fifth column is the correct answer.

```
public class TestGenerator {  


public static void main(String[] args) {

String TestBank[][] = {{"What color is grass?","A. Green","B. Red","C. Pink","A"},
{"Whats the first month called?","A. December","B. January","C. March","B"},
{"What shape is a soccer ball?","A. square","B. flat","C. round","C"},
{"what flys?","A. birds","B. pigs","C. dogs","A"},
{"what planet are we on?","A. Earth","B. Venus","C. Jupiter","A"}};


for(int i = 0; i < TestBank.length; i++) {
System.out.print(TestBank[i][0]+" ");

for(int j = 1; j < TestBank[i].length; j++) { 
System.out.print(TestBank[i][j]+" "); 
}
System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Im having extreme difficulty in connecting the randomly selected numbers from array SelectedNumbers to TestBank and trouble with getting those questions to output in different windows like this:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What color is grass?\nA. green\nB. red\nC. pink");
number = Double.parseDouble(input);
kitchen.setLength(number);
```

It will be deeply appreciated if someone could help me with this. Im new to Java so please keep it as simple as possible and explain to me how you figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: Consider trimming your question down to only the pieces of code that are specifically relevant to your question.

Comment: @Blue yes, but try to maintain some format `}}}` is a bit hard to read.

Comment: Could you indent your code, please? Would make it more readable.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. What have you tried, and where is `SelectedNumbers` defined?

Comment: Also, in general, I think you'd be better off creating a data object for your test questions. It would have at least three instance variables: the question text, a `List` of choices, and which of the choices is the *correct* answer. (Alternatively, you could store the correct answer by itself and then have a list of wrong answers.) Then you'd just have an array of question objects. Using position to know what pieces of data are where tends to be error prone, harder to read, and harder to change in real world applications. (That's why I despise Excel.)